# Opencart Tracking

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

im trying to display a tracking number for a product on opencart.

so once the order has been placed. i then add a tracking number to it. from which i wish the customer to be able to see on the order history.

```
// get tracking details
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'order_history'.`tracking_number`;

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$rates = array();
foreach($query->rows as $result){
    $rates[] = $result;
}
```

> $this->data['tracking'] = $tracking;

this would also go in order.php

this is what ive written but it dont work, im not expert at php, i dabble in it. hopefully someone can point me in the right direction,

so this code would go into controller/account/order.php

then on the template i assume i can just insert
`<?php echo $tracking; ?>` to display tracking deteails.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Off hand, I can see that this code will result in error, because your quotes/backticks are out of place:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'order_history'.`tracking_number`;
```

Should be more along these lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT `tracking_number` FROM `".DB_PREFIX."order_history`";
```

And, assuming you're going to want to pull an order-specific tracking #:

```
$sql = "SELECT `tracking_number` 
        FROM `".DB_PREFIX."order_history`
        WHERE `order_id` = 'MUFFINS'";
```

Do yourself a favor and use the double quotes when preparing a MySQL query. It's easier to wrap your stuff in single quotes without having to escape.

As for the remainder of the code, these are not rates but tracking numbers. Assumedly, there would be one tracking number to return per order, which you could wrap up into a single line of code like so:

```
$my_tracking_number = $this->db->query("

    SELECT `tracking_number` 
    FROM `".DB_PREFIX."order_history` 
    WHERE `order_id` = 'MUFFINS'

    ")->row['tracking_number'];

if ( !empty($my_tracking_number) {
    $this->data['tracking_number'] = $my_tracking_number;
}
```

However, if you're going to associate more than one tracking number with an order you can either insert a BLOB column in your order_history table and insert/query serialized data, or create a separate table entirely where multiple rows can be associated with a single order ID.